# How to set styles for different id's and the same classes

Tags: html, css

If I have multiple IDs `id1`,`id2`,`id3` sharing common CLASSes like`.selectize-input` and `.select-dropdown`.

Now I have to do

```
#id1 .selectize-input, #id2 .selectize-input, #id3 .selectize-input {};
#id1 .selectize-dropdown, #id2 .selectize-dropdown, #id3 .selectize-dropdown {};
```

Is there any easier way for setting styles like this?

**Note:** I do have other selectors to which I will apply different styles. So I do need this feature.

Comment: Why do you have to include the id? Just use the class itself to say the rules...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're applying the same thing to every ID I see no reason as to why you would need to indicate each ID, simply use the class to apply it. If you really want to do this you can use multiple selectors (though you'll need to do some testing to see what works for you).

I.E.

```
.selective-input#id1#id2#id3
```

Though this really just condenses your syntax, may make it more confusing if you're expecting others to read your code (note: proper syntax is always a good habit).

Comment: Hmm... this way doesn't seem to work in my R Shiny Code. My original way works. Are there any other aspects that I need to pay attention to?

Comment: From the css I've seen the only the other things I could think of would be make sure you are correctly IDing your classes/ids. By that I mean, make sure you're taking the correct path and there is not something overlapping it or a css item overturning your changes further down the sheet. I assume that's probably not it however, so probably best to fiddle with it, if all else fails, your code really doesn't struggle with readability too bad, just a little repetitive.

Answer (score 3):

I think it should look like:

```
[id^="id"].selectize-input {};
[id^="id"].selectize-dropdown {};
```

Comment: Thanks for the regular expression selector. Really helps.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't include the id, just the class name, when defining the rule...

```
.selectize-input {};
.selectize-dropdown {};
```

If you've got a problem with specificity then this should be sorted out elsewhere in your stylesheet. It's generally a good idea never too use ids for styles.